# why is my var being changed in the while loop?

Tags: c, linux

I need to make a program that takes some system commands like `ls`, `date`, etc. and checks if there is a path that includes this command(file). I have variable `commandandparameters` that starts to change in the last `while` loop and I dont know why.

I put `puts(commandandparameters);` to show that the output is not good if you want to run it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void main()
{
    char *arr[5];//for the command and his parameter
    char command[10];
    int i,j;
    char *path=NULL,*tempath,*finalpath,*commandandparameters;
    do
    {
        i=0;
        printf("enter new command:");
        gets(command);
        arr[i]=strtok(command," ");
        while(arr[i]!=NULL)//save the command and also the parametrs
        {
            i++;
            arr[i]=strtok(NULL," ");
        }
        strcpy(commandandparameters,arr[0]);//add first command
        for(j=1;j<i;j++)//add the parameters
            {
                strcat(commandandparameters," ");
                strcat(commandandparameters,arr[j]);
            }
        //now we check if the command in every path
        path = getenv("PATH");
        tempath = strtok(path,":");
        while (tempath != NULL)
        {
            strcpy(finalpath,tempath);//get the current path
            puts(commandandparameters);
            strcat(finalpath,"/");//we add '/'
            execl(finalpath,commandandparameters,NULL);
            tempath = strtok(NULL, ":");//get next path
        }
    }while(command!="leave");
}
```

Comment: don't use `gets()` which can lead to overflow, prefer `getline()` or `fgets()`

Comment: Show 1) respect, 2) efforts, 3) expected behaviour, 4) result (or error message) you get. Then it will be possible to help...

Comment: Note that it should be `int main(void)`; on Unix systems specifically, and according to the C standard, `main()` returns an `int`.  The value returned is the program's exit status, reported to the shell or other program that launched the program.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't defined the space that `commandandparameters` points at:

```
char *path=NULL,*tempath,*finalpath,*commandandparameters;
...
    strcpy(commandandparameters,arr[0]);
```

You have a pointer pointing to random space; you copy over that random space.  You will get funny results. If you're lucky, the program will crash.  If you're unlucky, it will misbehave.

You have a similar problem with `finalpath`:

```
    path = getenv("PATH");
    tempath = strtok(path,":");
    while (tempath != NULL)
    {
        strcpy(finalpath,tempath);
```

Worse, you're also butchering your environment.  The string returned by `getenv()` should be treated as read-only unless you are intending to modify the value of PATH.  As it is, you won't have much of a PATH left (no PATH if the first element on it is `:`) after the loop.

Make sure you know where every pointer is pointing.

Your code has so many potential buffer overflows it is hair-raising.  Don't use `gets()` ever; assume it will blow your computer to smithereens.

---

If you fix those problems, the `do { ... } while (command != "leave");` loop is tantamount to an infinite loop.  You can't compare strings usefully like that; you need to use `strcmp()`.

---

> I try to do a simple program and I see that `execl()` not work; can someone tell me why "ls" command don't work?

Here's a slightly modified version of your code from the comment.  I added two headers, and newlines to the printing, but the crucial change is in the `execl()` line.  Your original is in the comment; the working version is not a comment.  I can't decide whether that's your main problem or a typo in the comment.  The code as amended compiles and runs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    int pid, stat;

    if ((pid = fork()) == 0)
    {
        execl("/bin/ls", "ls", NULL);
        //execl("/bin/", "ls", NULL);
        printf("1\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        wait(&stat);
        printf("2\n");
    }
}
```

---

The code in your program demolishes PATH; if you fail to execute the first program, thereafter, it only looks in the first directory on your original PATH.  You're trying to use `execl()` to deal with a variable number of arguments; this is the wrong tool for the job.  You must use `execv()` or one of its relatives (`execvp()` would do the PATH-search without messing up the PATH, for example).  The reason is that `execl()` requires a set of arguments terminated by a null pointer, but you can only write that when you know how many arguments there are.  You could write:

```
execl("/bin/ls", "ls", "-l", (char *)0);
```

but unless you force every command to have at most 4 arguments (given `char *arr[5];`) and use a template such as:

```
execl(finalpath, arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3], arr[4]);
```

you can't use `execl()` to execute the command. But that limits users to at most N arguments, which is not acceptable.  (For example, shell expansion of `*` can produce a list of 30 or more arguments.

Your code also did not append the command name to the path component; the first argument to `execl()` is the path of the program executable.

So, use `execv()` (or `execvp()` or `execve()` or even, if you have it, `execvpe()`).  Here's a more or less minimal modification of your program that works OK if the command you execute is found; it is a minor disaster if it is not.  It's a one-shot shell; it doesn't `fork()` and `execv()` like it should — and if you forked before munging the path, the path mangling would matter less, though the process run would have a minimal to non-existent path.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *arr[5];//for the command and his parameter
    char command[100];  // Not 10
    int i;
    int j;
    char *path=NULL;
    char *tempath;
    char finalpath[200];
    char commandandparameters[200];

    do
    {
        i = 0;
        printf("enter new command: ");
        if (fgets(command, sizeof(command), stdin) == 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "EOF or error\n");
            break;
        }
        arr[i]=strtok(command, " ");
        while (i < (5-1) && arr[i]!=NULL)//save the command and also the parameters
        {
            printf("arr[%d] = %s\n", i, arr[i]);
            i++;
            arr[i]=strtok(NULL, " \n");
        }
        arr[4] = 0;

        strcpy(commandandparameters, arr[0]);//add first command
        for (j=1;j<i;j++)//add the parameters
            {
                strcat(commandandparameters, " ");
                strcat(commandandparameters, arr[j]);
            }
        printf("Cmd&Params: %s\n", commandandparameters);

        //now we check if the command in every path
        path = getenv("PATH");
        tempath = strtok(path, ":");
        while (tempath != NULL)
        {
            puts(commandandparameters);
            strcpy(finalpath, tempath);//get the current path
            strcat(finalpath, "/");//we add '/'
            strcat(finalpath, arr[0]);
            puts(finalpath);
            execv(finalpath, arr);
            tempath = strtok(NULL, ":");//get next path
        }
    } while (strcmp(command, "leave") != 0);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: i fix a lot of things but stil the program dont do the job and than i try to do simple program and i see that execl not work can someone tell me why "ls" command dont work
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    int pid,stat;
    if((pid=fork())==0)
      {
        execl("/bin/","ls",NULL);
        printf("1");
 exit(1);
      }
    else
      {
         wait(&stat);
         printf("2");
      }
}

Comment: @AsafShay: See my amended (extended) answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are only storing pointers returned by `strtok()`, they will point into `command`. Each iteration of the loop will overwrite `command`, thus causing the data pointed at by the "old" pointers to be changed.

You must copy out of the tokens out of `command`, either into dynamically allocated memory (look up `malloc()`) or have e.g. an array of staticallly-sized strings. Take care with buffer overflows, in that case.